# rails s command issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-5

The `rails s` command is showing this issue bellow; I have no idea what it is? this project use to run fine; I haven't change much either.

```
[vns@betito perseus]$ rails s
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:932: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = v8::Handle<v8::Value>; _Alloc = std::allocator<v8::Handle<v8::Value> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = v8::Handle<v8::Value>&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__builtin_expect(__n < this->size(), true)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My env:

```
Fedora 28
ruby 2.5.1
rails 5.2.0
libg++ 8.1.1
```

The weird thing is that I execute the same command in another project and it run just fine.

I am missing something?

```
[vns@betito perseus]$ rails 
The most common rails commands are:
 generate     Generate new code (short-cut alias: "g")
 console      Start the Rails console (short-cut alias: "c")
 server       Start the Rails server (short-cut alias: "s")
 test         Run tests except system tests (short-cut alias: "t")
 test:system  Run system tests
 dbconsole    Start a console for the database specified in config/database.yml
              (short-cut alias: "db")

 new          Create a new Rails application. "rails new my_app" creates a
              new application called MyApp in "./my_app"


All commands can be run with -h (or --help) for more information.
In addition to those commands, there are:

/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:932: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[](std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = v8::Handle<v8::Value>; _Alloc = std::allocator<v8::Handle<v8::Value> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::reference = v8::Handle<v8::Value>&; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion '__builtin_expect(__n < this->size(), true)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

If I try the command along it work but it got broke at the end.

Comment: Can you reproduce that with `ruby -v` or any other trivial Ruby code? Looks like your Ruby installation is broken somehow.

Comment: [vns@betito perseus]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: It run fine it is just only in that project, somehow

Comment: At least that runs. If the Ruby process crashes it's usually a sign of a bad build or a bad install. Is this on a brand new, untouched Rails project?

Comment: old rails project

Comment: Try on a new project, then see what gems might be causing the issue. Some with compiled extensions could be the culprit here.

Comment: I also thought; testing it

Comment: It seems to be this 'gem "less-rails"'; thanks for the advice

Comment: If you can narrow it down and confirm that, a self-answer would help as this is likely going to sting someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be this '**gem "less-rails"**'; thanks for the help

I removed the gem and the server run fine; I have to check if there is a old version for this that works.

the issue is related to this [_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS](https://github.com/rstudio/httpuv/issues/133) compilation flag was turned on by default in Fedora 28; and it causing a lot of software malfunctions.

[Fedora 28 wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/HardeningFlags28)

[Bug 1574797](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1574797)

more updates:
I found the issue and it is related to 'therubyracer' lib
There is a bug with the use of vector out of bounds.

to this line:
return &vector[0];

on file: ext/v8/rr.h#L223

so now that the libstdc++ 8.1 is checking with assertions ON.

I tested it using my own branch library and it is working.